# Can't access array/property inside JSON object

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

I have a JSON object (checked with `typeof`) and I am trying to access an array which is a property of my object. Issue I am having is that I can not get it to output anything when I to object.property

Here is my object, I am trying to access the `users` array inside this object. This object is assigned to a variable called `policy` when I do `policy.users` it gives undefined.

Is there something special about dealing with arrays inside objects I am missing?

```
{
    "_id": "5cb1fcc8fa3da31baf238bdb",
    "users": [
      "5c8d2a0c2f1f881e2377a601",
      "5cb14773c000525a8dfed406"
    ],
    "companyID": "62137607-0f1b-49a0-88e9-a2989447f4b2",
    "name": "My Policy",
    "createdAt": "2019-04-13T15:14:16.651Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
```

Comment: Please show us your code where you're trying to access the `users` property.

Comment: @eol It doesn't matter the long form of the code, what matters is how to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the object schema, I believe you are using mongodb (mongoose). If so you need to add the "users" property in the "policy" schema. Like this:

```
users: [{
  type: String
}]
```

Comment: Thank you! Your reply reminded me that I changed the schema in the service that creates the policy but not the lambda function that processes them. Just made the schemas match and it worked.

For anyone looking I had to add `users: {
  type: Array,
  required: true
 },`